# C#: using volatile fields with Interlocked

Tags: c#, multithreading, volatile, memory-barriers

My understanding is that all the `Interlocked` APIs in .NET will introduce a full memory fence. However, I still see many examples where `volatile`, which introduces half-fences, is used in conjunction with `Interlocked`. An example of that is `Task.Id`:

https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Task.cs,784864bc4dc294af

```cs
        private volatile int m_taskId;

        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                if (m_taskId == 0)
                {
                    int newId = NewId();
                    Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_taskId, newId, 0);
                }

                return m_taskId;
            }
        }
```

In instances like this, what is `volatile` actually doing?

Comment: `volatile` wouldn't appear to be doing anything in this particular case.

Comment: Volatile does a couple of things: it ensures the compiler doesn't make optimizations that would interfere with the proper use of the variable; and, _on some platforms_, it will ensure that the value set in one thread is visible in another. Note that the Intel x86/x64 architecture implicitly addresses the latter goal, but this is not the case on every other platform.

Comment: @PeterDuniho That makes sense, but don't interlocked operations ensure both of those things too? Or is that specific to the `volatile` keyword and the `Volatile` API?

Comment: _"don't interlocked operations ensure both of those things too?"_ -- no. Interlocked operations affect the sites in the code where the interlocked operations are actually done. The compiler has no way to know when optimizing code that uses a variable, whether that variable has been used in a call to an `Interlocked` method elsewhere or not. Similarly, a memory fence in one thread only affects reordering of read and/or write operations in that thread; you need another fence in other threads to do the same thing, otherwise the operations can still be reordered in a problematic way.